# A button inside a ToggleButton template cannot be clicked when the toggle button IsChecked=true in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, togglebutton

I faced a problem which tried to fix but was not successful. So, there is a derived from a ToggleButton (Silverlight 5) class EditableToggleButton that have its own template:

```
<!-- Editable Toggle Button -->

<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditableToggleButtonTemplate"
                 TargetType="customControls:EditableToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                
            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBorder"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                    Value="Visible" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </vsm:VisualState>
            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="NormalBorder"
                Margin="1,2,1,2">
            <Button Content="TEST BUTTON" Width="50" />
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="HoverBorder"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Background="#ececec"
                Margin="1,2,1,2">
            <Button Content="TEST BUTTON" Width="50" />
        </Border>           

        <Border x:Name="PressedBorder"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                Background="#FF807974"
                Margin="1,2,1,2">
            <Button Content="TEST BUTTON" Width="50" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="customControls:EditableToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{StaticResource EditableToggleButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

The EditableToggleButton class does not contain any logic:

```
public class EditableToggleButton: ToggleButton
{
}
```

The problem is that when an EditableToggleButton instance is in checked state, the "TEST BUTTON" button inside its template can not be pressed and, as a result, does not fire "OnClick" event. At the same time, the OnMouseHover event is working. I have analyzed the usages of the IsChecked property of a ToggleButton's code in ILSpy but did not find an answer of such behavior. Could you help to make the inner button clickable? Thank you!

Comment: I forget to add that in Normal state the "TEST BUTTON" work OK. I have no idea why it does not fire OnClick event in the Pressed state.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can edit your question, no need to add information via comments. Why do you want to have a button inside a button? What do you ty to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A toggle button instance has checked and unchecked states and I need this functionality to switch on/off some graphics layers. At the same time names of the layers are shown in the toggle button as its content. Moreover, I want to add 2 buttons "Edit" and "Delete" so that an user can edit a layer's name or delete it. As a result I have a toggle button and 2 buttons inside it which are not clickable when the parent button is checked.

Comment: I fixed it by deriving not from the ToggleButton class but from ButtonBase class and implementing IsChecked logic manually. Now it works.

Comment: Ok. In its current state your question is not really useful to other users and you found another way to implement your requirements. Maybe you just delete the question. Otherwise you risk downvotes.

Comment: Can't find a "delete" button for the question. How to delete it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware that you can't delete it.